# Average on a count() in same query

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on an assignment which requires me to find the average on the number of resources for each module. The current table looks like this:

```
ResourceID   ModulID
   1            1
   2            7
   3            2
   4            4
   5            1
   6            1
```

So basically, I'm trying to figure out how to get the average number of resources. The only
relevant test data here is for module 1, which has 3 different resources connected to it. But I need to display all of the results.

This is my code:

```sql
select avg(a.ress) GjSnitt, modulID
from 
(select count(ressursID) as ress 
 from ressursertiloppgave
 group by modulID) as a, ressursertiloppgave r
group by modulID;
```

Obviously it isn't working, but I'm currently at loss on what to change at this point. I would really appreciate any input you guys have.

Comment: Can you not just use your outer query (`AVG()` grouped by ModulId) without the inner query? I would think that would produce the expected results.

Comment: The problem with AVG() is that it takes the value put together, and takes the average on the single value. As an example, Resource 1,5 and 6 makes 12. Which it then uses to take the average sum. I need it to be 1.5, as there are 3 resourceIDs connected to ModulID 1.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is the query you are executing, written in a slightly less obtuse syntax.

```
SELECT
  avg(a.ress) as GjSnitt
  , modulID
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(ressursID) as ress 
   FROM ressursertiloppgave
   GROUP BY modulID) as a
CROSS JOIN ressursertiloppgave r    <--- Cross join are very very rare!
GROUP BY modulID;
```

You are cross joining the table, making (6x6=) 36 rows in total and condensing this down to 4, but because the total count is 36, the outcome is wrong.
This is why you should never use implicit joins.

Rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT AVG(a.rcount) FROM 
  (select count(*) as rcount 
   FROM ressursertiloppgave r
   GROUP BY r.ModulID) a
```

If you want the individual rowcount **and** the average at the bottom do:

```
SELECT r1.ModulID, count(*) as rcount
FROM ressursertiloppgave r1
GROUP BY r1.ModulID 
UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'avg = ', AVG(a.rcount) FROM 
  (select count(*) as rcount 
   FROM ressursertiloppgave r2
   GROUP BY r2.ModulID) a
```

Comment: I get the value for the first modulID, which displays the correct result. But how do I get the rest of the modulIDs to follow? When I include modulID in the first select, and does a group by modulID, I get the same result displayed by every modulID.

Comment: Ah, I see! But I think I've been clumsy with my question. What I'm looking for is an average on every rowcount, if that's possible.

Comment: @Coss, you cannot have an average per rowcount. It does not make sense. id = 1 Rowcount = 3 so what's the average? You need to have different values for rowcount to calculate an **average** rowcount. Not unless you want the average of the `ResourceID`, in which case you just add `avg(resourceID)` but an ID is just a random number, so what do you want with **that** average?

Comment: I see your point. It looks good like it is now I suppose. But I just wany to say that I really appreciate your help! Think the code looks decent, especially compared to my mess. So thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution

SELECT AVG(counter)
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(column to count) AS counter FROM table
) AS counter

Note that the nickname {counter} was added in SELECT COUNT and at the end of the inner SELECT

Answer (score 0):

You could also divide the number of values (7) by the number of *distinct* values (4) :

```sql
SELECT count(*) / count(DISTINCT ResourceID)  
FROM   resurrectfromgrave
```