# Counts and Averages in same query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

I have the below query and I'm looking to add averages to the query.

```
SELECT 
    CNTS.ID, CNTS.LOCATION, CNTS.CLASS, CNTS.DATE_YYYYMM, 
    CNTS.PHONE_Contacts, CNTS.VISITS, CNTS.Total_Contacts 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         A.ID, A.LOCATION, A.CLASS, A.DATE_YYYYMM,
         SUM(CASE WHEN a.IST =1 AND a.RCH = 'Contact' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS VISITS,
         SUM(CASE WHEN a.IST = 0 AND a.RCH = 'Contact' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Phone_Contacts,
         SUM(CASE WHEN a.RCH = 'Contact' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Total_Contacts
     FROM 
         (SELECT DISTINCT 
              *,
              CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), [DATE], 112) AS DATE_YYYYMM,
          FROM z) A
     GROUP BY 
         A.ID, A.LOCATION, A.CLASS, A.DATE_YYYYMM) CNTS
```

Desired Output

```
id      class    date_yyyy    phone_contacts    vist_contacts    total_contacts    avg_phone_contacts_perid    avg_visit_contacts_perid    avg_total_contacts per id

1        start    201501           2             1                 3
```

Comment: Use `avg()` as well as `sum()`.

Comment: Avg_Phone_Contacts = Sum of all contacts/distinct id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain single row totals - let your outer query aggregate data too. With appropriate GROUP BY clause.

You have already grouped data per ID, Location, Class and Date - now group by higher granularity level. It is impossible to obtain `avg_phone_contacts_perid` while you are requesting separate row per each id. Unless your desire is to see the same value of `avg_phone_contacts_perid` in every row (for example to make a comparison) - this is possible to do by windows function `AVG(...) OVER (...)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be so simple if you use avg() and sum() function or You should nest it into one more sub-query as answered here.

[Average on a count() in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893631/average-on-a-count-in-same-query)

However you can also try out sql variables or artificial join column.