# SQL for Ranking products by vote

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new in SQL.
I'm developing a function which rank products. Each product was rated by user, with score from 1-5 star. I want to select 5 top products which have highest score and most popular (rated by many people).
How could I write sql?

Description:

Tables:

```
- Review table -
product id,
user id,
score

- Product table -
product id,
product name

- User table - 
user id,
user name
```

Each user could rate for many products

Expected return: 5 product ids which have **highest score and  most popular** (rated by many people).

Sample data:

```
A: 5, 4, 4, 3, 1 (5 voted)

B: 5, 4, 3 (3 voted)

C: 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1 (6 voted)

D: 5 (1 voted)

E: 5, 4 (2 voted)

F: 5, 5 (2 voted)
```

D is highest score but not popular, C is most popular but low score. I want to select best product which has high score and popular also.
Please give me advice about the case.

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you only want the product id then the product and user tables are irrelevant, and what do you want to do about draws?

Comment: I want to select 5 best quality products, ranked by vote and score (via add review, one user is a vote and they set a score for product). Could you re-check updated sample data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average on a count() in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893631/average-on-a-count-in-same-query)

Comment: It really depends on how you want to go about it.
For example, surely you want the things with the highest rating and popularity first, but what about if that isn't the case? What happens when something isn't popular, but has a high rating? What happens if something has a high rating but isn't popular? How do you expect these cases to come out in order?

Comment: You're totally right. I couldn't define what is best product, most popular or high rating has more impact. In real world, which product is the best. Could you give me advice, even about mindset? Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

You want a weighted ranking

Here's an example of a weighted ranking

```
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | A | B | C | D | E | F |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | 5 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
    | 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 5 |   |
    | 4 | 3 | 1 |   |   |   |       
    | 3 |   | 1 |   |   |   |       
    | 1 |   | 2 |   |   |   |       
    |   |   | 1 |   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+
  r |3.4|4.0|1.3|5.0|4.5|5.0|
  v |5.0|3.0|6.0|1.0|2.0|2.0|
  m |6.0|6.0|6.0|6.0|6.0|6.0|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 WR |2.0|2.0|1.2|1.6|1.9|2.0|
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

where

```
WR = (v/(v+m))*r+(m/(v+m))
```

R = average rating for an item

v = number of votes for that item

m = an (almost) arbitrary constant. In the example above, it's equal to the total number of items.

Comment: You are now in possession of as much information as I had when I began answering this question.

Comment: I found out a case study here http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/72033.html. It really fits my needs, as your recommended keyword "weighted ranking". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, COUNT(score), AVG(score)
FROM product p
INNER JOIN review r ON r.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN `user` u ON u.user_id = r.user_id
GROUP BY r.product_id
ORDER BY AVG(r.score) DESC, COUNT(r.score) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Review table. You can just simply add two field in the Product table:

- rate_avg:  the average review for this product
- rate_total:  the total number of reviews

You would use rate_avg to ranking products when making a sql query, so the highest score of review products will be shown to customers.

Every time a new review is made, just update rate_avg & rate_total field by:

- rate_avg = (rate_avg*rate_total + new_review_value) / (rate_total + 1)
- rate_total = rate_total + 1