# How Can I Average a Summed Column

Tags: mysql

I've written a query (shown below) which counts the number of communications we've sent to each individual lead record in our database.

```
SELECT 
  lead_id,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id = 7 THEN 1 END) as COUNTSENDS
FROM lead.table
JOIN activity.table USING (lead_id)
WHERE lead_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-04-01'
  GROUP BY lead_id
  HAVING COUNTSENDS != 0
LIMIT 100
```

I now want to be able to see the average number of communications sent to customers over a period of time. However, it looks like you're unable to average an aggregated column which I tried to do:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id = 7 THEN 1 END)) as AVGSENDS
FROM lead.table
JOIN activity.table USING (lead_id)
WHERE lead_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-04-01'
  HAVING COUNTSENDS != 0;
```

Is there a way to average an aggregated field? I've only been able to find this posting: [Average on a count() in same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893631/average-on-a-count-in-same-query)

Comment: Do a two stage, the first stage grouping and counting to the time interval and the second stage averaging the counts i.e. `SELECT z, AVG(x) FROM(SELECT z, COUNT(*) AS x FROM t GROUP BY z, period)) GROUP BY z`. Right now there is nothing to average; you get a single count per lead id; there is nothing to AVG in a single number

Comment: `SUM(type_id = 7) / COUNT(DISTINCT lead_id) as AVGSENDS`?

Answer (score 0):

Following up as I found a good way to do this defining a macro.

```
define macro counts 
(
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id = 7 THEN 1 END) as COUNTSENDS,
  lead_id
FROM lead.table
JOIN activity.table USING (lead_id)
WHERE lead_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-04-01'
  GROUP BY lead_id );

SELECT avg(COUNTSENDS) as AVGSENDS
FROM $counts;
```